# ios 11 - password filling in an app

Tags: ios, ios11, password-protection

I've got an app and would like iOS 11 to remember the password.

I don't have an associated web-site - just the app.

Is that possible?

Some might ask why not just remember the password within the app?

I can't for non-technical reasons - best would be ios to do it.

Comment: Use the iOS keychain: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/iPhoneTasks/iPhoneTasks.html

Comment: The solution I'm looking for would be for iOS to do the prompting/saving and auto-fill - just like a Safari website. I'd like to display 2 input fields with the current contentTextTypes and let iOS manage the rest.